# GWT-GIN vs Raw Guice

Tags: java, gwt, guice, gwt-gin

Is there any reason why I can't just use Guice for DI inside a GWT application? If so, why? If not, what does GWT-GIN *really* offer that POG (plain ole' Guice) doesn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guice depends pretty heavily on reflection, which isn't really fully supported in GWT.

Comment: So what happens when I try to compile my Guice-injected GWT code into JavaScript? Does the compilation fail or does the generated code just not work?

Comment: I believe the compilation should fail, but I'm not positive.  As I understand it, GIN works out the injection details at compile time so GWT doesn't have to deal with the reflection.